# Centralized Tracking of User's log in multiuser python App

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, wxpython

I developed UI(User interface) application in python,this application can be accessed by n-number of users at same time(multiuser business application).

please help me to build centralized logger program which give all user log information while accessing UI-business application, logger program result should be like Eg: user,error,warnings,time stamp,query fired etc. later this information will be stored in database(i will take care about storing to db).
For this i triad below,but no luck to get all user logger info.

```
 import logging
 logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                     format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                     datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M',
                     filename='/temp/myapp.log',
                     filemode='w')
 console.setLevel(logging.INFO) 
 logger1.debug('Quick zephyrs blow, vexing daft Jim.')
 logger1.info('How quickly daft jumping zebras vex.')
 logger2.warning('Jail zesty vixen who grabbed pay from quack.')
 logger2.error('The five boxing wizards jump quickly.')
```

please advice the right code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you Twiggy package (BSD license), it makes easy this job.
You can create a "main" logger object and when you call the method fields(...)
it returns a new logger object with the fields parent plus the new fields.
For example:

mylog.py

```
import twiggy as twg

twg.quickSetup()

logs = {
    'user1': twg.log.fields(user='user1'),
    'user2': twg.log.fields(user='user2')
}
```

In other file you can call the appropiate logger in this way:

```
import mylog

mylog.logs['user1'].error("Start script")
```

The output will be

> ERROR:user=user1:Start script

This is only a simple example.

You can customize the output, filtering messages and add other output targets (also a DB).
It's simple and pythonic.

http://twiggy.wearpants.org/